# Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'Foo[]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, typescript, ramda.js

I am using **ramda** `map` and `forEach` methods but when I hover over to the `result` variable. It gives the following error:

**Type 'void[]' is not assignable to type 'Foo[]'.**

The data type `Foo` and the code is correct, I am sure about that.

**I know I am missing a `return` statement. I am not sure where to add that.**

Can anyone help me with this issue?

```
interface Foo {
  a: number;
  d: number;
  c: number;
}

const col = ["a", "d", "c"];
    const arr = [{ a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 }];

    const ress: Foo[] = map(_item => {
      const item = _item;
      forEach(c => {
        const val = item[c];
        delete item[c];
        item[c] = val;
      }, col);
    }, arr);
```

Comment: you aren't returning any thing from `map`. its not clear what you want to do

Comment: @DanielA.White can you please look at it now. I updated the code

Comment: You have to have a `return` statement within map, otherwise you're not getting anything back from it.

Comment: @M-N Yeah I know that but I am not getting that where to add it. Can you please fix it?

Comment: It is very rare in SO history that a person who comments here also answers the question.   You people ask questions as if you are breaking down the problem to help and then poof, gone

Comment: @newbie: People make comments in order to help you improve the question so that *someone* might be able to answer it.  A commenter who notices some ambiguities in your question might ask for clarification, even with no insight into or interest in solving it.  Such folks are still doing a real service; and your complaint is unfair to them.  It's worse when I look at your profile and see that you've asked around twenty questions here but never once answered anyone else's question.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I try to answer but don't have that skill set yet that is why I don't answer. I would love to help in future. :)

Comment: @newbie.  Your [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30356615) was five years ago.  I can't believe that you have gained no skills in that time worth sharing.  I'm guessing that if you looked around on tags for tools/languages/libraries you do use, you would quickly spot questions that you could answer.  Just keep it in mind, as that is how SO works, a mutual sharing of skills and knowledge.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes sir it is an old account but I was not using it. I got active very recently. Sure I will keep your words in mind and will try to answer from now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this much more simply:

```js
const col = ["a", "d", "c"];
const arr = [{ a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 }];

const project = (col, arr) => 
  arr .map (o => col .reduce ((a, b) => ({... a, [b]: o [b]}), {}))

console .log (project (col, arr))
  //~> [{a: 1, d: 3, c: 2}]
```

This function already exists in Ramda, [`project`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#project).

We could just do this:

```js
const col = ["a", "d", "c"];
const arr = [{ a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 }];

console .log (project (col, arr))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
<script> const {project} = R                                         </script>
```

But if you are not using it to create a proper subset of the object properties,  I would suggest that you really shouldn't need this functionality at all.  All it does is to create a new version of the object with properties added in a specific order.  But objects should logically be treated as *unordered* collections, so it seems wasteful.

If you are really using it for a subset of properties, the Ramda version is available.  But the first version above also seems a reasonable substitute.

Comment: Thank you so much Scott for your help. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: const col = ["a", "d", "c"];
    const arr = map(
      item => pick(col, item),
      data
    );  // [{ a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 }];

    project(col, arr)

Before project operation, I am performing pick and map operation. How can I combine these 2 operations into one statement?

Comment: @newbie: I'm not following what you want.  But it sounds as though it should be a different question.

Comment: How can we combine these two operations into one? const arr = map( item => pick(col, item), data ); AND project(col, arr)?

Comment: @newbie: I still don't really understand.  `project` is, in essence, `map (pick)`.  You shouldn't need to combine them.

Comment: Sorry I am not able to explain it well here. let's leave it btw thanks a lot for your help and time :)

Answer (score 2):

`map` function always maps (converts) one thing to another. means it takes something and returns something

but here u are not returning anything so it's taking `void` as the `default`

I think it should be like this

```
const col = ["a", "d", "c"];
    const arr = [{ a: 1, c: 2, d: 3 }];

    const ress: Foo[] = map(_item => {
      const item = _item;
      forEach(c => {
        const val = item[c];
        delete item[c];
        item[c] = val;
      }, col);
      return item
    }, arr);


  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the help :)